# Send html input to views.py in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to send input text from index.html to my view function that is "result".
When I click the 'Generate Summary' button its shows csrf verification failed.Csrf token missing.Urgent help required.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Input
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

def home(request):
    input=Input.objects.all()
    template=loader.get_template('home/index.html')
    context={
        'input':input,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def result(request,input_text):
    Input.input_text = request.POST('input_text')
    return HttpResponse("<h1> text is"+Input.input_text)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Title</title>

        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel='stylesheet'href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type='text/css'/>
    </head>
    <body background="/static/home/img/bg.jpg">
        <center><h1> <font color="white" >Summarizeit.com !</h1></center>

        <form name="myform" action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <center><label for="abc">Input Text</label>
                <input type="text" name="input_text"class="form-group"   id="abc"placeholder="Text input">
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">  Generate Summary !</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

home/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

finalproject/urls.py(Root Project)

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('home.urls'))
 ]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Input(models.Model):
    input_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.input_text
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See      https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'y)m04wnmm%i_#uih%^j5&aqeozlp!gt#px&z!*uf=-%v98x#-i'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition 

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'home',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]

 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'finalproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'finalproject.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME':  'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
 },
{
    'NAME':   'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
 },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Show us the settings.py file.

Comment: What version of django are you using? Alot of the code you're using to render a template looks very old... and nothing is calling your results view

Comment: Also I think results in not being called..please suggest a remedy

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you're rendering your template the hard way, which bypasses all the automatic things that Django does for you: most importantly, running context processors that include the CSRF token.

Your view should be this:

```
def home(request):
    input=Input.objects.all()
    context={
        'input':input,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

Note also that your setting of `Input.input_text` in the result view makes no sense at all; you need to create an instance of Input, set its input_text, then save it.

Comment: I thought it takes input_text from models.py

Comment: And one more thing I think results view is not being called...home function is being called again...Can u suggest something?

Comment: I don't know what your first comment means. For the second, you don't seem to have defined a URL for the result view.

Comment: url(r'^result/' , views.result,name='result')

Comment: I added it in urls.py and changed form action to '/result/'

Comment: Still it is opening the same page on clicking